# First value of my PHP Array is returned as 'null' when it has a value

Tags: php, mysql

I'd really like some help with the following MySQL / PHP problem (maybe bug?)

I'm trying to retrieve and display an array of data from my database using MySQL / PHP, but when I echo out the array, it returns the first value as 'null'.

So, even though the database has the following info:

```
"Example 1", "Example 2", "Example 3"...
```

The php echos out:

```
"null", "Example 2, "Example 3"
```

I would imagine this would be a common problem, but I haven't managed to find the required information elsewhere on the internet, so I'm hoping you kind folks can help.

**My PHP**

```
/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($conn) {
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT column FROM table WHERE approved = '1' ");

    // declare empty array to fill later
    $result = array();

    // make sure the MySQL pointer is looking at the first row
    mysql_data_seek($fetch, 0);


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        foreach ($row as $value) {

            $row_array = $value;

            // push info into new array with just the value
            array_push($result, $row_array);
        }
    }
}
/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($result);
```

**UPDATE**

New code courtesy of [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b):

```
if ($conn)
{
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE comment_approved = '1' "; 
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $result[] = $row['column_name'];

}

}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($result);
```

**NOTE:**

The 'null' problem still occurs with or without the:

```
 mysql_data_seek($fetch, 0);
```

as that appears to do nothing.

Any help would be great!

**SOLVED**

Thanks to [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) who pointed out that the problem was probably in the database rather than the PHP, it turned out there was the character ` lurking where there should have been a '. This caused the information to appear 'null'.

Comment: why you use seek? it is already at 0 in the beginning? and yes, use `or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I don't think you need the mysql_data_seek() function, since mysql_query() should return the result set with the pointer at 0 already. You should really only need that if you're reusing the same data set after iterating through it (like you are in your while loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE approved = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row['column'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

You shouldn't have to do the seek, as you've not done anything with the result at the time. And since you're only fetching a single column from the database, there's no need for the inner foreach() loop either.

Comment: +1 for writing what I was going to write and saving me the typing!

Comment: Thanks very much for your input, I've tried the above code and also removed the 'seek', but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: You may want to look at the data in the database. Run the query manually in the mysql monitor. PHP won't create a null entry unless the data's coming out of the query with a null in it.

Comment: I'm in PHPMyAdmin, running the above SQL query brings 10 results, all of which have the correct information, however when run on the website it brings 10 results, but the first is 'null'. :/

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about here? Other than overly-large blobs and possibly unicode text that's corrupted, I can't think of anything that'd cause mysql and/or php to convert a field's data into "null" in something so simple.

Comment: It's quotes actually... only a few words per entry. I can provide the link here: http://www.qwota.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/qwota/list-comments.php?term=example

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row)` on each loop iteration. I'm sure you'll see the null in there, which means it's coming out of the database like that. PHP doesn't magically convert something to null unless you tell it too.

Comment: Hmm... hold on, I've changed the ORDER BY and now the null has moved... maybe that input has corrupt / incompatible characters? I'll check...

Comment: Bingo! You were right, the database had the character of ` instead of ' - it was stopping the information from coming through. Any idea of how I can stop people inputting non-uniform characters?

Comment: I would give you a TICK, but as I'm still a n00b, SO won't let me. But thank you very much!

Comment: That's a data sanitization problem. You'd need to filter out anything non-legit before inserting it into the db.

Comment: You can accept answers on question even as a n00b, there is a time delay before you can do it, though. No worries either way.

Comment: Ah, great. I've ticked the answer, but I'll have to get more 'rep points' before I can click 'useful'. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the call to `mysql_data_seek`. I see no reason why the MySQL pointer wouldn't already point to the first row at the first call to `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing mysql_data_seek($fetch, 0); as the pointer will already be on the first record if you have just made the query.